# Stacking taskbar and toolbars horizontally

Tags: windows, taskbar, icons, toolbar, ergonomics

I went to my cousin today and when I played on his PC I found the way he organized his taskbar very practical but forgot to ask him how he did it (and he never answers messages).

Basically he has no shortcut pinned to his taskbar but he has two toolbars below, one with normal-sized icons and another one with small-sized icons, so basically it's like his taskbar has 3 rows : one that only displays open windows, one with regularly used apps, and a third one with smaller icons and less regularly used apps.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Edit : I know you can right-click and add a toolbar which is basically a folder with shortcuts inside, I successfully added two toolbars with different sized icons but they are next to each other instead of being organized horizontally (on top of each other).

Edit : I FINALLY figured it out thanks to @harrymc. Basically all I had to do was :

1. Unlock the taskbar,
2. Right click on each toolbar I wanted to move,
3. Select "show title" and move them by grabbing the title text.

It's not intuitive at all and very inconsistent but I did it, at last.

Comment: Maybe using 3rd party software like Stardock. Hard to tell without a screenshot/picture.

Comment: If the taskbar is unlocked, you can drag a toolbar to above, thus creating a second line, and so on.

Comment: @harrymc I cannot do that, when I add a toolbar, it divides the taskbar to create an allocated space for the toolbar, and I can only resize it using my mouse to drag the separator. I forgot to mention I'm using Windows 10 and my cousin too. Do you think it has to do with my version of Windows? I believe I have the family edition and my cousin the professional one.

Comment: @spikey_richie I found no third party app that could possibly do this installed on his computer when I checked (he wasn't around to ask at that moment), but basically just imagine a normal taskbar but taller, and with 3 rows between the start menu button and the other corner (the one showing all apps running in the background) : one for open windows (so blank until you open something), a second one with medium icons and a third one with smaller ones. Everything else is at its right place (the way it should be when you unlock and stretch the taskbar, no "abnormal spacing" or anything).

Comment: Dragging toolbars is funny, not all can be dragged. It's possible, I have done it many times in Windows 10.

Comment: @harrymc Was it Windows 10 Pro? If not, which edition?

Comment: @harrymc Nvm, I figured it out by searching Google for "Windows 10 can't drag toolbars" (with the word you used), I will post the answer myself in case someone else has a similar problem in the future; thanks.